# Issue Installing OpenNLP

Tags: java, apache, maven, opennlp

I'm having an issue installing OpenNLP. I am hoping that the brilliance of the hive-mind of Stack can help me out here. I admit I'm not very familiar with using Java extensions/plug-ins, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have installed Maven. When I run `mvn --version` I receive the following:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: /Users/[my_name]/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_33, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

When I go to the OpenNLP directory, `/Users/[my_name]/apache-opennlp-1.5.2`, and run `mvn clean install`, I receive this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.151s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jul 07 12:53:54 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/[my_name]/apache-opennlp-1.5.2). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I don't completely understand this error. If someone could explain what I need to do to fix it, I would really appreciate it.

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the command from inside the `opennlp` folder: `/Users/[my_name]/apache-opennlp-1.5.2/opennlp`. For more details please check the [building documentation](http://opennlp.apache.org/building.html).