# Issue installing OpenNLP 1.8.3

Tags: java, maven, opennlp

I've been trying to figure out how to install OpenNLP by myself for a while now.

I have installed Maven, added it to PATH and am able to run `mvn -v` with the expected result.

Now I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377024/issue-installing-opennlp), tried the same command and got the same error. As the accepted answer on it states the Command should be used in the `/Users/[my_name]/apache-opennlp-1.5.2/opennlp` folder, I went to look for that folder but it's not there. This is how my `apache-opennlp-1.8.3` folder looks from a fresh Download:
[image: apache-opennlp-1.8.3]

Running `mvn clean install` in this folder yields the following result:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.055 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-05T14:32:56+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory. Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

If someone could help installing OpenNLP on Windows 10 I'd be insanely happy as everything I was looking for on Google didn't help me out. I also took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511243) which also didn't help clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you downloaded the pre-compiled version of OpenNLP 1.8.3.  If you look in the bin directory, you will see a file "opennlp.bat" and "opennlp".  On windows, you want to run `opennlp.bat`, almost everyone else should run opennlp.

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thanks